# How to read subset class for train and test data

Tags: tensorflow, keras

my data folder look like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2l58.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAXjs.png)

i want keras to read all the class which is class `1` ~ `7`

code :

```
train_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')
```

on my code above, when i run it gives me the output

`Found 2322 images belonging to 3 classes.`

it's wrong it should be

`Found 2322 images belonging to 7 classes.`

how can i achive the output that should be 7 class ?